# Is there an Excel formula to move a set of cells by a specific amount in each direction?

Tags: excel-formula

I tried using the OFFSET function to no avail. Essentially, I have a few cells and I need to move them by a user-specified amount in the x and y direction. How would I do this?

Comment: A formula returns a value into the cell in which it is placed.  It cannot put a value in a different cell.

Comment: Is there any way of working around this? I know someone at work has done this before, and I doubt they used VBA?

Comment: Then they filled a large range full of IF formula that return the correct value if the cells equal a designated number.

Answer (score 1):

In excel, a function like this one will populate multiple cells

```
Function populate()
    Evaluate "eventFinal(" & Application.Caller.Offset(0, 1).Address(False, False) & ")"
    populate = "result here >>"
End Function

Private Sub eventFinal(CellToChange As Range)
Dim numbers(2, 1) As Integer
    numbers(0, 0) = 25
    numbers(0, 1) = 21
    numbers(1, 0) = 3
    numbers(2, 0) = 4
    numbers(1, 1) = 2
    numbers(2, 1) = 6
    CellToChange.Resize(3, 2) = numbers
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid VB is the only way unless you 'cheat' a little...

I only illustrate the concept re: 'cheating' with this google sheet.

[image: Conditional format hack]

Google sheets "equivalent" with colour placement: [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1NQOmmjiS2l9gQLZjbahn-eYGaYkcMB9TeUnoUeB65sM/edit?usp=sharing).

The alternative would be block out a range of cells with functions such as:

```
=if(and(row(A1) - row(A$1) = row offset value, column(A1)-column(A$1 = column offset value), desired cell to move, "")
```

The suitability of this depends entirely upon the purpose: if your goal is a visual one where the actual values don't really matter, then google sheets example is one method but the value you place is quite limited (can only use values